# Spark Scala - Winsorize DataFrame columns within groups

Tags: scala, apache-spark, statistics, data-science

I am pre-processing data for machine learning inputs, a target value column, call it "price" has many outliers, and rather than winsorizing price over the whole set I want to winsorize within groups labeled by "product_category". There are other features, product_category is just a price-relevant label.

There is a Scala stat function that works great:

```scala
df_data.stat.approxQuantile("price", Array(0.01, 0.99), 0.00001)
// res19: Array[Double] = Array(3.13, 318.54)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't support computing the quantiles within groups. Nor does is support window partitions.

```scala
df_data
    .groupBy("product_category")
    .approxQuantile($"price", Array(0.01, 0.99), 0.00001)

// error: value approxQuantile is not a member of
//   org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset
```

What is the best way to compute say the p01 and p99 within groups of a spark dataframe, for the purpose of replacing values beyond that range, ie winsorizing?

My dataset schema can be imagined like this, and its over 20MM rows with appx 10K different labels for "product_category", so performance is also a concern.

```
df_data and a winsorized price column:
+---------+------------------+--------+---------+
|   item  | product_category |  price | pr_winz |
+---------+------------------+--------+---------+
| I000001 |     XX11         |   1.99 |   5.00  |
| I000002 |     XX11         |  59.99 |  59.99  |
| I000003 |     XX11         |1359.00 | 850.00  |
+---------+------------------+--------+---------+
supposing p01 = 5.00, p99 = 850.00 for this product_category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with, after struggling with the documentation (there are two functions `approx_percentile` and `percentile_approx` that apparently do the same thing).

I was not able to figure out how to implement this except as a spark sql expression, not sure exactly why grouping only works there. I suspect because its part of Hive?

Spark DataFrame Winsorizor

- Tested on DF in 10 to 100MM rows range

```scala
// Winsorize function, groupable by columns list
// low/hi element of [0,1]
// precision: integer in [1, 1E7-ish], in practice use 100 or 1000 for large data, smaller is faster/less accurate
// group_col: comma-separated list of column names
import org.apache.spark.sql._

def grouped_winzo(df: DataFrame, winz_col: String, group_col: String, low: Double, hi: Double, precision: Integer): DataFrame = {
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_table")
    
    spark.sql(s"""
    select distinct 
    *
    , percentile_approx($winz_col, $low, $precision) over(partition by $group_col) p_low
    , percentile_approx($winz_col, $hi, $precision) over(partition by $group_col) p_hi
    
    from df_table
    """)
    .withColumn(winz_col + "_winz", expr(s"""
        case when $winz_col <= p_low then p_low
             when $winz_col >= p_hi then p_hi
             else $winz_col end"""))
    .drop(winz_col, "p_low", "p_hi")
    
}

// winsorize the price column of a dataframe at the p01 and p99 
// percentiles, grouped by 'product_category' column.

val df_winsorized = grouped_winzo(
   df_data
   , "price"
   , "product_category"
   , 0.01, 0.99, 1000)
```